# how to hide img tag using pseudo elements

Tags: css

I have below piece of code and want to hide img tag using css pseudo elements.

```
<body>
     <div>
         <img src="hi.png">
         <div class="container1">
              <p>somevalue </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
         <img src="hi.png">
         <div class="container2">
              <p>somevalue </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<style>
    .container :: before{
display: none;
}
</style>
```

unfortunately above code is not working and my image is not being hidden. Please help me out how to get this done by using CSS.

In above code i want to hide only the image tag which is present before container2 class. I will have a cycle of classes (i just added only 2 for example) please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before):

> In CSS, ::before creates a pseudo-element that is the first child of the selected element. It is often used to add cosmetic content to an
>   element with the content property.

By using `.container::before`, you aren't targeting the element before .container, you're simply creating a new element there.

You can see this when you try this code:

```
.container::before {
   content: 'lol';
}
```

One way to hide your img element using pseudo-classes would be to use for example

```
img:first-child {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Merkur0, I have below code and want to hide the image element which is present before container2 class only. How we can do this? please help me out.<body>
     <div>
         <img src="hi.png">
         <div class="container1">
              <p>somevalue </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
         <img src="hi.png">
         <div class="container2">
              <p>somevalue </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

Comment: Well, you could always give the image element that is before container2 some class or id and then only apply  display: none to that element.

Comment: Hi Merkur0, I'm not able to get or fetch the image element before container2 class. Could you please send with sample? i understood display:none we have to apply but how to find img tag which is present before container2 element???

Comment: If you want to do this dynamically (meaning always target the element that is before container2 instead of hardcoding it in HTML), you can do this with the Javascript `previousElementSibling` property. Here's an example - https://codepen.io/merkur0/pen/KYxMQo